# Uber API and Uber APP doesn't return the same price

Tags: uber-api

I am playing with the Uber API (https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/api/v1-estimates-price) and I don't understand why I have two different estimation price for UberPOOL for the same trip at the same time.

On the Uber app, the surge multiplier is 1.4 and the estimation for Uber Pool is 10,20$ and for Uber X is 13,56 and more.

But on the API, the surge multiplier is 1.0 with the estimation = 7,40$ for UberPOOL and the surge multiplier is 1.4 with the estimation = 12-15$

So the result is the same for Uber X but not for UberPOOL.

I asked @UberDevelopers on Twitter but for the moment the only answer i have is "Surge varies by product (in both API & Uber app)."

Do you have any ideas ?

[image: The problem]

Comment: Hello, Uber is looking into this internally. Have a few theories but nothing concrete at the moment. Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).